# Mojave screen saver starts randomly

Tags: imac, mojave, screensaver

I have a new Mojave (10.14.1) installation on an iMac (Retina 5K, 27-inch, 2017).  My screen saver is set to start after 5 minutes.  I have a hot corner defined to start the screen saver.

I have noticed that periodically, the screen saver just starts up out of the blue.  Typically this happens while I am scrolling with the magic mouse.  I am definitely not hitting the hot corner.

Any suggestions for why this is happening and how to stop it?

Comment: You could eliminate the hot corner from the list of possibles by either adding a Cmd key to the corner, or just removing that corner temporarily.

Comment: Try a reboot of the computer

Answer (score 1):

It turns out another Mac had an idle screen sharing session open to this computer.  After closing that, I have not experience the screen saver start.